# Reducing False positives ML models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, precision-recall

Is there a nice way to enforce a limit on the false positives while training a ML model?

Let's suppose you start with a balanced dataset with two class. You develop a ML model for binary classification. As the task is easy the output distributions will be peaked respectively at 0 and 1 and overlapping around 0.5 . However what you really care about is that your false positive rate is sustainable and cannot exceed a certain amount.
So at best you would like to have that for pred > 0.8 you only have one class.

At the moment i'm weighting the two class to penalise an error on the class "0".

```
history = model.fit(..., class_weight={0:5, 1:1}, ...)
```

As expected it does decrease the fpr in the region pred > 0.8 and of course it will worsen the recall of class 1.

I'm wondering if there are other ways to enforce this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your problem , you can consider one-class classification svm. This article can be useful : https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-with-one-class-svms-5403a1a1878c  . The article shows also why one-class classification is better to consider instead of some other classical techniques , such as oversampling/undersampling or class-weighting. But of course it depends on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Thank you! That's an interesting article. I already tried with anomaly detection but i think my dataset is kind of strange. The perfromance on that were ok but a simple model with unbalance could do better by at least ~10% in the recall for the same fpr.
I will take a look at other techniques on outlier detection, they seem interesting